# Displaying a UIButton on UITableView cell

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want to display a customized button with "!" as its text inside a UITableView cell. The code is like this:

```
UIButton *informationBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[informationBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 55, 55)];
[informationBtn setTitle:@"!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[informationBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(popUpWindowWithMessage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:informationBtn];
```

where "cell" is defined as a UITableViewCell instance.

But the button doesn't appear on the cell. What should I do to display the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct, And it seems the button is there. But you can't see it. Change the color of button title. other than white. then check..

```
[informationBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Add the above line after setting title of your button.

Comment: Ah, this is something I've never thought of.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding the button to the cells `accessoryView`, you can do this:

```
[cell setAccessoryView: informationBtn];
```